# Increasing the width of the outputlabel on visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to increase the width of the outputlabel on Visual force page , but i am not able to .

I gave style="width:30%"(as an example ), gave it in pixel to , but it wouldn't change. Any suggestions or ideas would be highly appreciative.

Thanks

Comment: are you enclosing this inside a pageblockitem/ pageblock if so try to apply the style on to the pageblock element.

Comment: Welcome to the SFSE and thank you for posting a question.  Do you have any code that you can post?  It usually helps to post the code that is giving you problems, so that people can better identify the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Add `display:block`

```
<apex:outputLabel value="Hello World" style="display:block;width:150px;" />
```

Comment: I have been beating my head over this on and off for months. I try for a while and then give up. THANKYOU!